# Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined (index):21 initialize ( Google Maps API )

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Keep on getting this error in the console "Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined". Been doing it for a while now but no luck. Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
 <head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
<style type="text/css">
  html { height: 100% }
  body { height: 100%; margin: 0; padding: 0 }
  #map-canvas { height: 100% }
  </style>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
<script type="text/javascript">
   function initialize(location) {

  console.log(location);

  var mapOptions = {

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(location.coords.latitude, location.coords.longitude),
      zoom: 8
    };
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"),
        mapOptions);
  }

  $(document).ready(function()
  {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(initialize);
  });
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div id="map-canvas"/>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You call `initialize` without any parameter.

Comment: See example [Using geolocation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebAPI/Using_geolocation).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There was problem in `script` declaration in your code. You missed to close `script` tag for `jquery` and hence google map js wasn't load properly.

Just change below...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"**[[Problem is here]]**</script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
  src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false">
  </script>
```

and it should work fine.

Here's [Demo](http://jsbin.com/APAsUga/1/edit)

Comment: I was stuck for more than one day the mistake i was doing was including the api script before jquery

Answer (score 0):

For me

Adding this line

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

Before this line.

```
<script id="microloader" type="text/javascript" src=".sencha/app/microloader/development.js"></script>
```

worked