# ui-map google is not defined

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, angular-ui

like the title says when i try to use ui-map module i receive that error.
I have try to use this sample http://jsfiddle.net/sjmcpherso/9kF7d/

on my pc, i have add to the dependencies ui-map and ui-event too, but when i start the application the console log say google is not defined, more precisly at the fifth row of my code

that's my code
http://jsfiddle.net/Lw9XW/

```
//Add the requried module 'angular-ui' as a dependency
angular.module('maptesting', ['ui.event','ui.map','ui.directives']);

function MapCtrl($scope) {
var ll = new google.maps.LatLng(13.0810, 80.2740);
$scope.mapOptions = {
    center: ll,
    zoom: 15,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};

//Markers should be added after map is loaded
$scope.onMapIdle = function() {
    if ($scope.myMarkers === undefined){    
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: $scope.myMap,
            position: ll
        });
        $scope.myMarkers = [marker, ];
    }
};
   $scope.showMarkerInfo = function(marker) {  
    $scope.myInfoWindow.open($scope.myMap, marker);
};
```

Comment: i have found the problem with two similar topic, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358431/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-index21-initialize-google-ma

Comment: I have solved the problem following the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20358431/uncaught-referenceerror-google-is-not-defined-index21-initialize-google-ma